# Call user control button click event when loaded dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I have a web application that assigns time duration to students in a day kind of a scheduler.

so for this i have a user control as TimePeriod and this control is loaded dynamically on the web page.

My User-control contain two textbox and one button control and i need to find click event of that button.At this button it should retrieve value of two related text-boxes.But i am not able to find click event of this button.

This User-control loaded on another page on event of submit button on that page.
But the number of that user control on a page varies so for this i have user a code that dynamically creates a list of user control.

For example purpose i have set `j` value up to 10, actually it varies Looks like this:

```
for (int j = 1; j < 10; j++)
{
    TableRow row = new TableRow();
    TableCell cell = new TableCell();

    cell.Text = j.ToString();
    cell.Height = 10;
    cell.Width = 75;
    row.Height = 10;
    cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromKnownColor(System.Drawing.KnownColor.Gray);
    //cell.BackColor = #FFFFFF;
    row.Cells.Add(cell);

    TimePeriod ib = (TimePeriod)LoadControl("TimePeriod.ascx");
    TableCell cell1 = new TableCell();
    cell1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromKnownColor(System.Drawing.KnownColor.Gray);
        cell1.Controls.Add(ib);
        row.Cells.Add(cell1);

        tbl1.Rows.Add(row);
    cell = null; row = null;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to ensure that the event is added on each postback of the page. Don't limit it to the first pageload i.e. `!Page.IsPostBack` as is common.

Also you need to contruct and load your dynamic controls on `Page_Init` not `Page_Load` or anywhere else. It's a common mistake. If you construct on `Page_Load` or anywhere else then they don't get added to `ViewState` and cause problems